# Calculate the integral for the arc length of $y = \frac{e^x + e^{-x}}2$ from $-1$ to $1$

Tags: calculus, integration, arc-length

I know to set up this integral you find the derivative: 
$$y' = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}2dx$$
Then you set up the arc length function: 
$$L = \int^1_{-1}\sqrt{1 + (\frac{e^x - e^{-x}}2)^2 }dx $$

However I don't know how to solve this integral. Please help.

(Note: No knowledge about $\sinh$ and $\cosh$ and the related stuff.)

Comment: Did you try computing the term inside the square root? It factors.

Comment: Is it $\frac{1}{2(e^x-e^{-x})}$ or $\frac{1}{2}(e^x-e^{-x})$?

Comment: Also, *please* format your post; you've posted nearly twenty questions, several of which you've properly written.

Comment: Others helped me format the other ones. ^^It's the second one

Comment: Then please read the [formatting guide](http://www.meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) and look over the edits people made to your older questions.

Comment: I'm sure this is really a question about hyperbolic functions. Have you studied them? If not I'd recommend looking at those first.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

$$1+(\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}2)^2=1+\frac{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}-2}4=\frac{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}+2}4=[g(x)]^2$$

Then compute

$$\int^1_{-1}g(x)dx$$